# put installed app model in selected database

Tags: python, django

I have installed app named `registration-redux`, and I would like to store user data (and some other minor things) in a sqlite database called `default`. However, the data structures get added automatically to other databases, which is redundant.

Normally, I go to *models.py* and put in a desired model a label:

```
class some_model(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'default'
```

And in *settings.py* I select which models go to which database:

```
DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING = {'market_data': 'market_data',
                         'registration': 'default'} # this doesn't work

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'market_data': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'market_data.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Now, when I migrate `market_data` database, redundant structures like `auth_user`, `auth_group`, etc. get added. How can I omit them?

Comment: You're suppose to use a router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Django 1.7

Create file *routers.py*, and in this file write:

```
class Market_data_router(object):
    def allow_migrate(self, db, model):
        if db == 'market_data':
            if model.__name__ != 'Market_data':
                return False
        return None
```

In *settings.py* write:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['routers.Market_data_router']
```

At the end, create ,,clear" database:

```
./manage.py migrate --database=market_data
```